# No voltage on injector lines following engine rebuild

Tags: electrical, ford, electronic-control-module, fuel-injectors, fiesta

I have a 2012 Ford Fiesta 1.4 L TDCi.

It was starting normally but the engine had major mechanical problems so I have rebuilt it and put it back in without touching any electrical part. Now I'm trying to start the engine but no luck so far.

Here's what I've tested so far:

- tested the injector plug with light bulb and a multimeter during the ignition and startup but there is no 12 V on them (the black wire has no voltage in reference to plus or minus side of battery and the red wire has 1.2 V in reference to ground)
- checked for continuity from the plug to the ECU and it's good
- also checked the power relay that supplies the ECU (the big one 40A) and it's working but it is hot while ignition on.

What should I do now? The 1.4 TDCi engine also known as 1.4 HDi.

---

**Update**

The engine turns fine with no weird noises when cranking and no smoke is coming out. and after someone suggested that the fault could be the lack of fuel pressure in the rail so the ECU won't fire the injectors (which turned out to be right).

I removed the fuel tank while trying to get to the fuel pump because it was not making any noise to find that there is no pump only the fuel level sender. 
Now I have the fuel in jug plus a manual pump connected to the fuel filter, I pump the fuel and crank to find that the injectors started to get 12v signal now and some black smoke is coming out but it didn't start yet as the batteries are dead now. I noticed that it doesn't have great suction on the intake for now.

Comment: I suggest you read, or get someone to read, the codes as that may point you in the correct direction.

Comment: In have read the codes and there s none except for "clutch switch" which is definitely unrelated .

Comment: Do you have wiring diagrams for the car?

Comment: Please clarify whether the engine cranks or turn when you try to start it up, or whether it doesn't turn at all. Great question!

Comment: @Ben not even the user manual.

Comment: @Chebhou "Clutch switch?" Most manual-transmission cars will not start unless the clutch is depressed. If the clutch switch is bad, disconnected or has an intermittent fault, the computer may refuse to provide spark. (Though, in many cases, it will still turn the engine over - it just won't start.) For the power relay: they will get warm, which is normal. If it's really HOT, make sure it's installed in the correct orientation.

Comment: @david it turned out to be bad electrical connection problem the car is running now fine

Comment: @Chebhou glad you got it fixed. For future reference: there are typically three lines going to the injector: power, ground and signal. Even if the ECU doesn't want to open the injectors by sending a signal, they'll still get +12V on the power line. Also, I thought that, by 'hot', you meant temperature, not 'has power.' :/

Answer (score 2):

Based on you update, it sounds like you have a fuel delivery problem. You were right to check in your fuel tank, but you should find your fuel pump in there. Usually the sender unit and pump are built onto the same "arm".

If that is working okay (it's getting voltage and running) then you should check your fuel pump relay. It will be under your hood and is a small relay that will click when you flip the key to On (but not start). Sometimes giving it a shake is all it needs. I'm serious.

Hope this helps with your issues!

Comment: There s no pumps in this model by design ,it is said that the high pressure pump will suck the fuel by creating vacuum in the feed line.

Comment: Try checking all you fuel lines for leaks. Possibly something has a leak from when you put it back together? Also check the relays.